# Loopback AngularJS Get _id field from MongoDB Collection

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, loopbackjs, loopback, angular-loopback

### Loopback AngularJS SDK and Get Data

I'm newer with Loopback.js

I have a lot of collection in MongoDB and I thought index field is the best way to relationship with two collection. 
For example,

I have two collections. These are Projects and Job

They have "ProjectID" table for hasMany relation. The project collection has many jobs. Look at this image.

[image]

This is other picture for create collection from loopback gui.

[image]

My question: I tried get _id field (it is also ProjectID) from database.Here is:

```
// Get Projects Data
if (typeof Projects.find({}) != "undefined") {
   $scope.projects = Projects.find({});
}

console.log($scope.projects);
```

But my result is in this picture :

[image]

Why I can't access `_id` or `ProjectID` ? Do I any mistake?
If you know other good way for relation, you should tell me.
Thank you for answers.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem.

You don't need to create other field for collection relation.

Delete all ID fields (like ProjectID, JobID, etc...) and use

```
slc loopback:relation
```

command. Thanks to this command create relation with own collection id.

*The problem took my 5 hour, it maybe helpful other developer. Happy coding.*